# Correct usage of "but"

Tags: conjunctions, writing, coordination

Is it fine to use the following sentence:

> We propose an algorithm that has a reduced complexity but achieves only a fraction of the...

More specifically, do I need to add something (for instance: "that" or "which") after "but"?

Comment: Yes, no. And welcome!

Comment: Usually advised in personal business communication, so take it with a grain of salt: try replacing "but" with "and", it might sound better.

Comment: @VictorBazarov But "but" here is used to express the fact that "has a reduced complexity" is a positive aspect whereas "achieves only a fraction of the.." is a negative one. So you still think that "and" could replace "but" ?

Comment: @mat, it was unclear from your question what is positive, what's negative.  Try using "yet" instead, or put the negative first so you **end** on a positive statement.

Comment: @VictorBazarov you mean: "We propose an algorithm that achieves only a fraction of the region yet has a reduced complexity". Thank you!

Comment: Not knowing the context makes it hard to be sure but "We propose an algorithm that achieves only a fraction of the region yet has a reduced complexity". is weird. I just don't understand what "achieves only a fraction of the region" means. // I think you're trying to say "We propose an algorithm that considers only a fraction of the region but has a reduced complexity".

Comment: @VictorBazarov the context is the following: suppose there is an algorithm that lets the system acheives a certain region, so for sake of brevity we say that the algorithm achieves the entire region. Now assume that this agorithm is of high computational complexity, thus "we propose another algorithm that has a reduced complexity but achieves only a fraction of the region".

Comment: @mat, I am not sure what it means for a system to "achieve a certain region".  Let's hope that those who read your article/manual, will know what it means.  I'd probably replace "fraction of the region" with "partial region" (but check if it makes sense). **"We propose an algorithm that achieves partial region yet has a reduced complexity"**.  Also see if you could claim "**notably** reduced" or "**significantly** reduced" to emphasize the accomplishment.

Answer (score 1):

Your sentence is correct as is.

It would be incorrect to add "that" or "which" after "but."

*Source: Native speaker*

Comment: I disagree that "that" or "which" is necessarily incorrect.  It can be useful as a clarification, like "this is an algorithm...which achieves only a fraction of X"  Here's an example in live usage: ['I call this sphere, which is established with the existence of man as man but which is conceptually still uncomprehended, the sphere of "between."'](https://books.google.com/books?id=A-aRUYInwMEC&pg=PA39&lpg=PA39&dq=%22but+which+is%22&source=bl&ots=Eeov_rKHXc&sig=wBxonZhGgA2pOWPWQgxQjr3zHuc&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CDAQ6AEwBTgUahUKEwiho__P1uXIAhULPD4KHSQkDXQ#v=onepage&q=%22but%20which%20is%22&f=false)